# Duplex WCF service channels continuously alive (WSDualHttpBinding)

Tags: wcf, duplex, wsdualhttpbinding

The arhitecture:

1. console application that contains a wcf duplex service;
2. windows app consumers; every app subscribe to Duplex, so we have a list of subscribers
   and the service must send notifications to some of them in case that some events apper;

The problem:

1. how to maintain the connection alive continuously so that the service can send notifications to clients ?

I found that there are 2 channels for this binding. I need to have permanently the channel from service (for callbacks) open.

Thanks;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as a client is connected to the service, the callback channel will be alive.  Once the client disconnects (or the channel gets faulted), the callback channel will close.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks. Can you tell me which is the best way to keep alive (24/24) the client connected and the channel in a non-faulted state ?

Comment: You could set high timeout values, but then you could run into other issues (resource constraints, for example).  What is driving the need to have the client connected all the time?  It almost sounds like you want the clients to act as listeners, and I'm not sure that WCF is the proper model for that.  In my understanding, clients are alive only for the length of time needed to complete the interaction(s) with the service.  The service itself can be set up to run as long as the host machine is up (as a Windows Service running a WCF servicehost, for example).

Comment: Yes, they are acting as listeners. Thanks. If not WCF, which is best design ?

Comment: That depends a lot on what the problem your solution is trying to address - i.e., what business process are you trying to model?  Can you give a description of what the service and the clients are doing (or what it is you want them to do)?

Comment: Something to consider from a WCF perspective is the publish-subscribe system Juval Lowry details in his book [Programming WCF Services](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-WCF-Services-Mastering-AppFabric/dp/0596805489/ref=dp_ob_title_bk).  An earlier version of that content is available in [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) from October 2006, but keep in mind it was based on the pre-release WCF 3.0.

Comment: Service must notify windows app clients when some events happen. Some events are not dependendent on clients interactions (new records in database), some of them are dependent (a client with super rights assigns a new issue to another client to resolve and, after the assignation, the client must be informed). The notification must be a windows os window on the machine which is running the client app. Thank you.

Comment: I'd definitely take a look at Juval Lowry's article that I linked to (getting his book would be even better).  His publish-subscribe model uses an intermediary publish/subscribe service that both the event publisher and the event subscribers use.  His source code is available with the MSDN Magazine article.

Comment: Yes, that pattern is the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem than you, to solve it you need to implement a keep alive method.  A dummy call to your service is kind of stupid to have a 24/7 WCF service because is not really the best architecture way of WCF but we know sometimes what we need is not always the best thing.

So yep, just implement a call to the WCF service every 5 minutes and by doing that you keep alive the connection.  Maybe you can have others problems too, in my case I don't have a lot of subscribers of the WCF service so this solution was fine.